# MockMvc access the MockHttpServletRequest object that mockMvc will use

Tags: spring, junit, controller, easymock, mockmvc

Is there anyway to get a hold of the actual request object that mockMvc will use when you execute:
mockMvc.perform(RequestBuilder requestBuilder)

I know that I can build the request myself (i.e)

```
Integer id = new Integer(1);
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/myPath").param(Constants.ACTION, Constants.GET_DETAIL)
  .param(Constants.ID, id.toString());
MockHttpServletRequest request = requestBuilder.buildRequest(wac.getServletContext());
```

but I cannot pass this request along as the mockMvc.perform method specifically only accepts the builder which will create a new instance of MockHttpServletRequest. I am using EasyMock which uses equals() in it's matchers (at least by default) and due to the lack of an equals() implementation in MockHttpServletRequest it simply compares the object ids. i.e

```
      EasyMock.reset(localeHelper);

  localeHelper.getLocale(request);
  EasyMock.expectLastCall().andReturn(locale);
  /* this matcher will always fail because the request object is rebuilt by the mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder) call 
    and MockHttpServletRequest does not have an equals() method that these mocking tools can fall back on for object equivalency */
  EasyMock.replay(localeHelper);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a capture.

```
Capture<HttpServletRequest> capture  = EasyMock.newCapture();
EasyMock.expect(localeHelper.getLocale(EasyMock.capture(capture))).andReturn(locale);
EasyMock.replay(localeHelper);

mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder);

HttpServletRequest request = capture.getValue();
// Then assert whatever you want on the `request` that was received in parameter by the mock
```